# MVVMCross Xamarin Forms - How to close the Hamburger menu upon click

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I am using MVVMCross Xamarin Forms MasterDetailPage and show the Hamburger menu . On click of any menu item, how to close the hamburger menu to its original position in left pane so that the main content is visible. Please help. Please note that the Application.Current.MainPage is not be used in ViewModel in Core project as it does not have reference to Xamarin.Forms and I have a separate UI project

[image]

[image]

Comment: From [MasterDetailPage Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.masterdetailpage?view=xamarin-forms),we could find that `MasterDetailPage` is obsolete as of version 5.0.0. Please use `FlyoutPage` instead.